# Web based SFTP Client

Tags: webapp-rec

Has anyone heard of an online FTP client that supports SFTP?

My web host only allows me to use SFTP, and I often work on computers on which I can't install a desktop SFTP client, or that disallow portable SFTP clients to connect through their proxy.

I'm looking for something like [net2ftp](http://net2ftp.com), but with support for SFTP.

Please note that it **needs to be online**, not a piece of software which you download and run on your computer, portable or otherwise. It also needs to be a free service (or at least the SFTP part of it needs to be); I don't want to sign up to a premium plan.

Comment: Monsta FTP is a web-based client offering FTP as well as SFTP/SCP. www.monstaftp.com (disclaimer: I'm involved with this project.)

Answer (score 0):

Our service [Codeanywhere](https://codeanywhere.net) is a web-based code editor with FTP and SFTP support, among other things.

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to mention in my post that the service needs to be *free*. I don't want to sign up to a premium plan. Thanks anyway